# FileNotFoundException after folder mount?

Tags: java, tomcat, symlink, filenotfoundexception, mount

I get the `java.io.FileNotFoundException` when uploading new files in  `C:\folders`

the `C:\folders` is a mount created like so:

```
mklink /D C:\folders \\IP_ADDRESS\folders
```

PS: the network access between the local server and the distant server (having IP_ADDRESS) is granted, also by using only the normal folders (C:\folders) without a mount it works.

OS : Windows

Server : Apache Tomcat

Please is it a question of permissions? or the creation of the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not mount a folder with mklink, you create a link. You should really map a netwrok drive instead:

```
net use u: \\IP_ADDRESS\folders
```

and tell your app to upload files to u:.

You might want to add the switch `/persistent:Yes` to make sure the mapping will persist after a reboot. Use `net use /?` to see all options.